# IIS url rewrite http to https subdomain 404 error

Tags: iis-8, url-rewrite-module

I'm trying to get my site to go from http://sub.domain.com to redirect to https://sub.domain.com on a company intranet and I want it to work for pages below subdomain as well. I have the url rewrite module installed on IIS 8 and I've tried adding the following in my web.config

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

But when I go to http://sub.domain.com I just get a 404 error, and I'm not sure how to debug this.

If I go to https://sub.domain.com I see the web page.

Thanks

Comment: Please get started from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Please also make sure you don't add the httprediret or other setting in the IIS to redirect the domain.